# Evaluating $\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{e^x}{1+e^{2x}}\mathrm dx$, alternate methods

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

**Problem:**

Evaluate $$\displaystyle\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{e^x}{1+e^{2x}}\mathrm dx$$

**My progress:**

I have actually solved the problem, but I fear that I may not have used the "desired" methods.

Using substitution $u = e^x$, we can rewrite the integral and get $$ \arctan(e^x)\bigg|_0^\infty $$

Then we need to evaluate the limit $$\displaystyle\left(\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\arctan(e^x)\right) - \arctan(e^0)$$

Now, this is where I think my solution differs from the intended method (which I don't know what is).

When I evaluate the above limit, I realize that $\tan(x)$ has a vertical asymptote for $x = \frac\pi2$, which means that $\arctan(x)$ has a *horizontal* asymptote for $y = \frac\pi2$, and is continuously increasing.

Then, since $x\to\infty \Rightarrow e^x\to\infty$, we can conclude that $$\displaystyle\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\arctan(e^x) = \frac\pi2$$ which gives the final answer $$\displaystyle\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{e^x}{1+e^{2x}}\mathrm dx = \left(\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\arctan(e^x)\right) - \arctan(e^0) = \frac\pi2 - \frac\pi4 = \underline{\underline{\frac\pi4}}$$

**My question:**

Is there a more "calculating" way of evaluating the aforementioned limit? I.e. using some general rules of limits rather than intuition? Bear in mind, I like my own solution. It was satisfying. I just feel like there is something else I should know, which I'm missing out on.

Comment: I'd say that this is _the_ method to calculate this integral.

Comment: That looks right to me.

Comment: Repeating  mickep's comment, this is the simplest method, not to say $The$ method. In any manner, the key problem is to get the antiderivative. After that, most problems are "simple".

Comment: $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\arctan(x)=\frac\pi2$, basically for the reason you described. (Remember that the range of the arctangent is $(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2)$, and that it's increasing.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to avoid the limit to infinity, you can use the change of variable $e^x=1/u$ instead, and get$$\int_0^\infty\frac{e^x}{1+e^{2x}}dx=\int_1^0\frac{-\frac{du}{u^2}}{1+\frac1{u^2}}=-\int_1^0\frac{du}{1+u^2}=-\arctan(u)\Big|_1^0=\frac\pi4.$$

Comment: For rigor, the limit notation should be used anyway, as this is an improper integral.

Answer (score 4):

If you know complex analysis, you can use the residue theorem.  Consider

$$ \oint_C \frac{dz}{\cos{z}} $$

where $C$ is a rectangle with vertices in the complex plane $-i R$, $\pi-i R$, $\pi+i R$,$i R$.  The contour integral is then

$$\int_0^{\pi} \frac{dx}{\cos{(x-i R)}} + i \int_{-R}^R \frac{dy}{\cos{(\pi+i y)}} + \int_{\pi}^0 \frac{dx}{\cos{(x+i R)}}+ i \int_{R}^{-R} \frac{dy}{\cos{(i y)}}$$

Now, the integrals over $x$ vanish because they combine to form

$$- i 2 \int_0^{\pi} dx \frac{\sinh{R} \sin{x}}{\sinh^2{R}+\cos^2{x}} = - i 2 \arctan{\left ( \frac1{\sinh{R}}\right )} $$

which clearly vanishes as $R \to \infty$.  Thus, in this limit, the contour integral is equal to

$$i \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dy \left ( \frac1{\cos{(\pi+i y)}} - \frac1{\cos{(i y)}} \right ) = -i 2 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dy}{\cosh{y}}$$

By the residue theorem, the contour integral is also equal to $i 2 \pi$ times the residue of $1/\cos{z}$ at the pole $z=\pi/2$ (the only pole within $C$), which is $1/(-\sin{(\pi/2)}) = -1$.  Thus,

$$ -i 2 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dy}{\cosh{y}} = i 2 \pi (-1) $$

and using the exponential definition of cosh, we get that

$$\int_0^{\infty} dy \frac{e^y}{1+e^{2 y}} = \frac{\pi}{4} $$

Comment: Killing a fly with a sledgehammer?

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: perhaps.  But this example is very interesting because the integral that is usually estimated and tossed away in this case may be evaluated analytically.  Thus, we may even determine the finite integral using the residue theorem in this case, very unusual.

Answer (score 2):

**Sorry for being late**
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^x}{1+e^{2 x}} d x & =\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{e^x+e^{-x}} d x \\
& =\frac{1}{2} \int_0^{\infty} \operatorname{sech} x d x \\
& =\frac{1}{2}\left[\tan ^{-1}\left(\tanh \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)\right]_0^{\infty} \\
& =\frac{\pi}{4}
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Another way not using the arctan is given by realizing that
$$
\mathrm e^x\left(\frac{1}{1+\mathrm e^{2x}}\right) = \mathrm e^x\left(\frac{1}{2(1+\mathrm{ie}^x)}+\frac{1}{2(1-\mathrm{ie}^x)}\right)
$$
Then the substitution $u=\mathrm e^x$ gives
$$
\int_1^\infty\left(\frac{1}{2+2\mathrm{i}u}+\frac{1}{2-2\mathrm i u}\right)\mathrm du=\left[-\frac{1}{2}\mathrm i\ln\left(\frac{\mathrm i}{2}+\frac{1}{\mathrm i+u}\right)\right]_1^\infty=\frac{\pi}{4}.$$

EDIT: I need to add some details concerning the complex logarithm: Observe that the argument $z=\frac{\mathrm i}{2}+\frac{1}{\mathrm i+u}$ satisfies $0\leqslant \mathrm{Im}(z)\leqslant\frac{1}{2}$ hence you can choose the principal branch of the logarithm and the limit is found using the continuity of the principal branch of the logarithm. I hope this clarifies the procedure.

Comment: Hem, how do you evaluate the complex logarithm and its limit ?

Comment: @ Yves: I edited my answer to explain the missing details. Thanks for pointing out that one has to handle complex logarithms with some care!

Answer (score 1):

Another way: note that on $(0,\infty)$, $e^{-2x}<1$, so we can use the binomial theorem, and interchange the order of summation and integration, to get
$$ \int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^x}{e^{2x}+1} \, dx = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x}}{1+e^{-2x}} \, dx = \int_0^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{k}e^{(2k+1)x} \, dx \\
= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k} \int_0^{\infty}e^{(2k+1)x} \, dx = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{2k+1} = \frac{\pi}{4}. $$

Justifying the interchange is a matter of bounding the "remainder" integral,
$$ \int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-2(n+1)x}}{1+e^{-2x}} \, dx, $$
which is easy to do by noting that the denominator is larger than $1$, so the remainder is smaller than $1/(2n+2)$.

Comment: From hte second expression I would substitute $u=\exp(-x)$ to go to $\int_1^0\frac{-du}{1+u^2}=-\arctan(u)\bigr|_{u=1}^{u=0}=0+\frac\pi4=\frac\pi4$, as in the question, but without the onus of taking limits.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\expo{x} \over
1 + \expo{2x}}\,\dd x} =
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\expo{-x} \over 1 + \expo{-2x}}
\,\dd x =
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\expo{-x} - \expo{-3x}\over 1 - \expo{-4x}}
\,\dd x
\\[5mm] \stackrel{4x\ \mapsto\ x}{=}\,\,\,&
{1 \over 4}\int_{0}^{\infty}{\expo{-x/4} - \expo{-3x/4} \over
1 - \expo{-x}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 4}\pars{%
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\expo{-x} - \expo{-3x/4} \over
1 - \expo{-x}}\,\dd x -
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\expo{-x} - \expo{-x/4} \over
1 - \expo{-x}}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 4}\bracks{\Psi\pars{3 \over 4} -
\Psi\pars{1 \over 4}}
\end{align}
See [A & S Table $\ds{\color{black}{\bf 6.3.22}}$ identity](http://people.math.sfu.ca/%7Ecbm/aands/page_259.htm).

With the *Euler Reflection Formula*:
\begin{align}
& \mbox{} \\
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\expo{x} \over
1 + \expo{2x}}\,\dd x} =
{1 \over 4}\bracks{\pi\cot\pars{\pi \over 4}} =
\bbx{\pi \over 4} \\ &
\end{align}